# Asp.Net webapi xml formatter not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I have created a **self-hosted service** with asp.net webapi framework and I've added a custom MediaTypeFormatter so that I can return html. My problem is that I want to use Jquery in my html so I have included the usual `<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>` in my template. When I browse to my url it serves the html perfectly but the GET for the jquery file returns 404.

I guess this makes sense as my "web server" doesn't know what to do with this request. So do I have to add a route and controller to serve files such as script and css files? Or is there an easier way?

If not I can just add jquery script directly into my template but I'd rather not if anyone has a better solution.

Comment: How is this related to asp.net web api ?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend serving jQuery from your self hosted site. The whole point of self hosting is to remove the dependency on ASP.NET MVC and all that comes with it. So given that, I think you have a couple of option if you want to serve scripts or other files.

1. Host the WebApi site inside of ASP.NET MVC, which will then give you the option of hosting jQuery as well.
2. Reference the jQuery script from a CDN like Google or Microsoft on your html page.
   See [CDN Hosted jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery) for more details.